# Rails activerecord query comparing two attributes of same record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking for a way to build a query that compares two attributes of the same record, without first pulling the record and comparing post-query. My specific case would potentially have 10k's of records, so iterating through each is not an option.

Example: Finding this record by querying .where updated_at == created_at

```
#<User id: 1, name: "xxx", created_at: "2012-07-01 12:00:00", updated_at: "2012-07-01 12:00:00">
```

Rails 3+, ActiveRecord, MySQL.

Update: As commentor Matzi points out, the following is valid when using sqlite, but not **mysql**:

```
User.where("created_at == updated_at")
```

**Solved**: Simple mistake, ruby vs sql.

Sqlite can use:

```
User.where("created_at == updated_at")
```

but MySQL requires:

```
User.where("created_at = updated_at")
```

Comment: What is the problem? You can use `.where` to this.

Comment: That's what I was hoping for, but have been searching with the wrong terms. Would you mind providing a quick example or a link to relevant documentation? Thanks in advance

Comment: This should work: `Users.where("created_at == updated_at")`

Comment: @Matzi User.where("created_at == updated_at") -----
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== updated_at)' at line 1: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (created_at == updated_at)

Comment: It works for me. Maybe try using single equation mark.

Comment: I just tried this in a new test project using sqlite, and this worked. I switched the same new project over to mysql, and it is no longer valid.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do this in a generic way, you should use ARel to get away from a specific database implementation. Something like

```
users = User.arel_table
User.where(users[:created_at].eq(users[:updated_at]))
```

would work

Comment: Please note that Arel is a private API and even though it hasn't changed often in the past few years, there's no guarantee that it won't break between minor versions of Rails.